# Центрировать div с position absolute по ширине родителя

Tags: html, css

Есть такая проблема: нужно, чтобы `div.preview-box #timeCodeContainer` находился по центру `div.preview-box`. Не знаю как это сделать максимально точно. И еще подскажите, точнее ли `transform: translate()` при выравнивании чем `margin:`? Вот код:

```css
div.preview-section {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  transform: translateY(-106%);
  margin-top: 200px;
}

div.preview-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #252323, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86));
  -webkit-background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #252323, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86));
  -moz-background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #252323, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86));
  -o-background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #252323, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86));
  -ms-background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #252323, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86));
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #363131;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #363131;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #363131;
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #363131;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #363131;
}

div.preview-box #frameContainer {
  width: 96%;
  height: 58px;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  margin: 1px auto 0px;
}

div.preview-box #timeCodeContainer {
  width: 34px;
  font-size: 0.70em;
  background-color: #171616;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="preview-section">
  <div class="preview-box">
    <div id="frameContainer"></div>
    <div id="timeCodeContainer">0:00</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разница между `margin` и `translate` не в точности, а в том, что для `margin` нужно знать абсолютные размеры позиционируемого элемента, тогда как для `translate` этого знать не нужно.

Суть позиционирования по центру в следующем. Вы даете дочернему элементу, который хотите отцентрировать с помощью `position`, сдвиг `left: 50%` и `top: 50%`. Эти проценты рассчитываются от размеров родителя. Таким образом левый верхний угол дочернего элемента находится как раз по центру родителя. Но сам дочерний элемент все еще не по центру, т.к. имеет размеры. Если они известны, например 100px ширина и 60px высота, вы можете применить `margin-left: -50px` и `margin-top: -30px`. Но что делать когда размеры не известны? Тут поможет `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`. Поскольку это свойство применяется к дочернему элементу то все проценты рассчитываются от его размера.

```css
div.preview-section {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  transform: translateY(-106%);
  margin-top: 200px;
}

div.preview-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #252323, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86));
  -webkit-background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #252323, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86));
  -moz-background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #252323, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86));
  -o-background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #252323, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86));
  -ms-background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #252323, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86));
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #363131;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #363131;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #363131;
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #363131;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #363131;
}

div.preview-box #frameContainer {
  width: 96%;
  height: 58px;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  margin: 1px auto 0px;
}

div.preview-box #timeCodeContainer {
  width: 34px;
  font-size: 0.70em;
  background-color: #171616;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="preview-section">
  <div class="preview-box">
    <div id="frameContainer"></div>
    <div id="timeCodeContainer">0:00</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что делать когда размеры неизвестны? А вот так их найти не вариант: `var element = document.getElementById("element");var elemWidth; window.onresize = function(){ elemWidth = element.clientWidth;}`? Это если ширина в процентах.

Comment: А зачем если есть простое решение на css - `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`? И хотя будут проблемы с ie8, но у клиента и js может быть отключен, тогда проблемы будут везде.

Comment: Я пошутил. Конечно CSS лучше.